# Unable to to install sslstrip in kali linux with "apt-get install sslstrip" causes error "Unable to locate package sslstrip"

Tags: linux, man-in-the-middle, kali-linux

I have a kali linux vm provided by my university. It doesn't seem to have sslstrip preinstalled.

When I try to install it, I get this error

```
root@kali:~# sudo apt-get update && apt-get install sslstrip

Hit:1 http://kali.cs.nctu.edu.tw/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Hit:2 http://downloads.metasploit.com/data/releases/metasploit-framework/apt lucid InRelease
Reading package lists... Done              
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package sslstrip
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. `sudo su`
   (then enter your password as usual)
2. `git clone https://github.com/moxie0/sslstrip`
   (once it is completely downloaded, access the directory)
3. `cd sslstrip`
4. `python setup.py install`
   (After that try checking the `sslstrip` if it already installed, by checking it on `airgeddon`)
5. `cd ../`
   (go back to home)
6. `cd airgeddon`
   (accessing `airgeddon` directory)
7. `bash ./airgeddon.sh`
   (then the `sslstrip` should be installed)

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded the setup files directly from the project page and installed. And it worked.

https://moxie.org/software/sslstrip/

Comment: That website no longer hosts anything to download...

Answer (score 0):

you can install it by typing this command :

pip install sslstrip

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

I hade also faced same problem. As the main setup link of sslstrip was missing. pip and apt-get were also not working. But after installing airgeddon, there came an option to install missing necessary files. From there sslstrip easily got installed. Have a try.
To install airgeddon:

1. git clone https://github.com/v1s1t0r1sh3r3/airgeddon.git
2. cd airgeddon
3. bash airgeddon.sh

Then follow the instructions

Answer (score 0):

I found `sslstrip`  as a **pip** project [here](https://pypi.org/project/sslstrip/). But unfortunately is only for python version 2 - 2.7 and `Debain` cut the support for it. One of the solutions might be adding those files manually on your `Debian` distro and then it might work.

Here is what the original page says:

> Project description
>
> sslstrip is a MITM tool that implements Moxie Marlinspike’s SSL stripping attacks.
>
> It requires Python 2.5 or newer, along with the ‘twisted’ python module.
>
> Installing:
> pip install sslstrip
>
> Running:
>
> sslstrip can be run from the source base without installation. Just run ‘python sslstrip.py -h’ as a non-root user to get the command-line options.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.